# Customer Account Data Types of Categories seems out of date

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/0005_service_features/0050_categorization

The schedule_c_categories listed here seems out of date. I see a lot more categories in my data than what is listed here.

For example, in my data, I see "Other Business Expenses", "Deductible Meals", etc...

Is there a more complete list of all schedule_c_categories intuit uses?

Also, while we are at it, is the regular category and sub-category list complete?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please submit a support ticket - https://developer.intuit.com/Support/Incident